# How can electric field and magnetic fields have x and y components in electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, vector-fields

Suppose an electromagnetic wave is travelling in z direction with electric field in x direction and magnetic field in y direction. Then how can electric field and magnetic field vectors have both x and y components?

I read a book which had a section for proving that electric field and magnetic field are perpendicular to each other.

The proof consisted of an equation dealing with the curl of electric field. Then x and y components of Electric field and magnetic field were found taking z components to be zero.
Where did these x and y components came from?

I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but the only physical statement (for a monochromatic EM wave) is that E-field and B-field are perpendicular to each other (E,B,k are mutually perpendicular).

Of course, by setting up a good coordinate system, you can make k (wave vector)pointing in the z-direction, E-field pointing in the x-direction and B-field pointing in the y-direction. However, you can pick another coordinate system, say rotate the above coordinate system about its z-axis by $\pi/3$, then your E-field and B-field get both x and y components. So it is all about the choice of the coordinate system.